# Shared object not found but is present in the linker directory

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have downloaded and build *boost_1_68_0* from source and got the following message:

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

```
/resources/boost_1_68_0
```

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

```
/resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib
```

The code compiles fine with this:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -I  /resources/boost_1_68_0  -L /resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib  regex.cpp -lboost_regex -o reg
```

When I'm trying to run the code I get this:

> ./reg: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.1.68.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, inside /resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib I do have the following files:

```
libboost_regex.so.1.68.0
libboost_regex.so -> libboost_regex.so.1.68.0
```

Is there a way to make it look for the shared object inside the */resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib* direcotory?

Thank you!

Using CentOS 7

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: @tink it's CentOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `/resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have root access on the machine, try:

```
echo "/resources/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/boost.conf
```

and re-run `ldconfig`.